# Transpose data and only keep needed obs

Tags: sas, transpose

I have one table displaying 3 obs and 4 fields (ID lastname, firstname and telephone number) for each of ID and I prefer to transpose lastname to 3 fields and for firstname field, I want to only keep the one associated with 1st last name and for telephone number, I want to only keep the one associated with 3rd (last) last name.

```
Table: 

ID Lastname FirstName TelephoneNumber 
001 Y       A         123 
001 W       B         345
001 Z       C         567
002 M       D         789
002 N       E         912 
002 L       F         934



Table want: 
ID LastName_1  LastName_2  LastName_3  FirstName TelephoneNumber
001 Y          W           Z           A         567 
002 M          N           L           D         934
```

Can anyone help out?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You are expected to show some own effort. Make sure you have read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The code I tried is to separate them first by lastname and merge. This approach works. But I just want to be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with PROC SUMMARY IDGROUP.  I will leave it to you to research the syntax.

```
data id;
    input (ID Lastname FirstName)(:$3. 2*:$1.) TelephoneNumber;
    cards; 
001 Y       A         123 
001 W       B         345
001 Z       C         567
002 M       D         789
002 N       E         912 
002 L       F         934
;;;;
    run;
proc print;
    run;
proc summary nway;
   class id;
   output
      out=id2   
      idgroup(out(firstname)=)
      idgroup(last out(telephonenumber)=)
      idgroup(out[3](lastname)=)
      ;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

Comment: Thanks. If I want to use this output data as other's input, how should the code be like?

Comment: @jen I modified the output statement to include the OUT= option to name the data set being created by OUTPUT statement.

Comment: Thanks.  If there are more fields (e.g., address, province), address is following the same rule as firstname and province is following is the sale rule as telephone number, how will the code change?